# permission denied upon mkdir

Tags: php, apache, debian, mkdir

I use `mkdir()` to create a directory on my server:

```
// $var_name is equal to an md5() hash
$path = "/var/www/publish/" . $var_name;
if(mkdir($path)) {
  echo "success";
} else {
  echo "error";
}
```

This will yield an error due to a permission denied. Looking up on my server, by doing `ls -lh`

```
drwxr-xr-x  2 root     root   4.0K Aug 17 09:05   publish
```

But if my `$path` is equal to `$path = "/var/www/" . $var_name;` it will create the folder I expected. What seems to be the issue in here.

Comment: @PLB it looks like publish already exists, so that is not the issue. However nobody but `root` having write access definitely will stop you making new directories (since who runs their web server workers as root...)

Comment: @Leigh Yes, right. That's why I deleted my comment and answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The permissions for the `/var/www/publish` folder are wrong. You need to make sure the apache user has the required permissions to create a directory.

You are able to create directories in `/var/www/` as it will have different permissions.

Check the name of the user that the httpd process is running as and `chown -R user:group /var/www/publish` to that user/group. On debian, this appears to be www-data/www-data, so you need to run the following command `chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/publish`.

Comment: can you elaborate more please?

Comment: "Check the name of the user that the httpd process is running as" - how to?

Comment: @LeandroGarcia in the defence of Chris here, he has answered your question correctly. However teaching you basic sysadmin skills is beyond the scope of what you've asked.

Comment: Pardon me for that, but it seems it's kind of unavoidable to ask it since it's almost the answer to the question.

Answer (score 2):

when using mkdir() with PHP it is executed with apache user (www-data on ubuntu), you may set the same rights on publish that you have on /var/www using chown

on ubuntu :

```
chown www-data.www-data /var/www/publish
```

Regards

mimiz

Answer (score 0):

Fix permissions for publish folder (owned by root!). An **insecure** way: `chmod 777 /var/www/publish`

It's better to run suphp and change owner of publish folder to your php user (+w permission).